# pigeonhole principle question related to divisability

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that we can pick $2$ numbers from the set of $4$ numbers $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ such that their difference is always divisible by $3$.

Comment: To apply the pigeonhole principle, try explicitly defining two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $|A| > |B|$, then creating a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ which relates the two sets in a way relevant to your problem. You can then conclude it is impossible for $f$ to be injective.

Answer (score 3):

We have $3$ possible residues modulo $3$ , namely $0,1,2$. Hence two of the numbers must have the same residue. If we subtract thenm the difference will be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thanks, but how to prove with pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @TeethatLaosuksakul The proof method used there *is* the pigeonhole principle.